Correct way to select data for (probabilistic) churn model?
Context: The team I work for would like to model the probability that a customer will churn given the specific covariates of the customer. We have two main ideas: a model using survival analysis and a model using a binary classification approach. My gut feeling is that the approach using classification is “wrong”, but I can’t fully explain why.
Question:
My question is, is this approach wrong, and if it is can we give some context as to “why” this approach is wrong? I would like to better my understanding.
Information:
Assume we have a large amount of panel data from customers with (time dependent) covariates X. In the classification approach, we follow the following recipe:

We chose a date that separates a ‘training’ set of data, from a ‘testing’ set of data. The training data is split into a ‘training’ part and a ‘validation’ part, used for calibration later on.
Each customer either has the product or does not, indicated by 1 and 0. We create a feature, y_target, by looking at product possession on t_0 and t_1. If a customer goes from 1→0, that is marked as a ‘1’ at t0. If a customer goes from 1→1, that is marked as a ‘0’ at t0. 0→0 and 0→1 are set to NA.
For the training set:
a.  As churn events are very rare, we select a single data point for each customer that had y_target = 1, at any point in time between the start and the end date.
b.  For the remaining customers, choose a single random moment in time for which y_target isn’t NA
For the validation and testing set:
a.  We select a single random moment in time for each customer
We train the model on the training set, we calibrate the model on the validation set, and we evaluate the model on the test set.

This picture illustrates the recipe:

Our goal is to create a model that can estimate P(y | X ) as closely as possible to the “real” probability; meaning that the model gives an estimate of the true probability that a customer will churn in the next time step, conditional on all the information we have of the customer at the current time. This probability score is important to use for other
The problem I expect with this way of constructing a dataset is that the resulting model will not give correct probabilities. I suspect that the model will be reasonable in identifying churners, based on their features in a ‘ranking’, or a ‘classification’ sense. If there is some characteristic feature identifying a churner, then I believe the model can learn that association pretty well.
In a way, by selecting random months and a single point of data from each customer, I am modelling the event that a random customer, at a random month, churns on the product, given that this customer has the product and a set of features. However, I feel that the model won’t give good estimates of the actual churn probability, based on the way that the data is created. I can’t however come up with good arguments why that is…
I feel that in a way you can’t compare the test and train set to each other, as whoever exists in the test set has ‘survived’ for longer than persons in the train and validation sets. On the other hand, it does seem to model the situation of how good I expect the model to be, once I start using it.
Another aspect that bothers me is that I am not using a lot of the data I have available. I have panel data from each customer, but I’m only using a single randomly selected data point per customer. I also don’t do anything with customers who already have churned (a long time ago). Does this lead to a less optimal prediction or a form of bias?
Is there anyone who could shed some light on this type of approach? Any help in the right direction would be much appreciated!
